# Coordinates of bounding box in Map composer

Tags: qgis, coordinates, print-composer

I would like to find a way to export the coordinates of the bounding box inside map composer. I know i can create labels with coordinates but I'm not able to define the lat/long of the corner of the map (fig 1)

[image]

I also followed this guide (https://gisunchained.wordpress.com/2014/09/09/coordenadas-dos-cantos-do-mapa-em-qgis-map-corner-coordinates-in-qgis/) but it gives the entire shapefile corners, aka the whole world in my case, instead of the area selected. I would like to have a similar output to this (fig 2) that i have in  tilemill.

[image]

Comment: Not sure why the guide is not working for you. You get the visibly map bound and not the entire layer bound, unless your map view is the entire bound. If you want an on the fly bounding box generator take a look at the new BoundingBox plugin available through the QGIS plugin repository.

Comment: okay figure it out, i had some problem with the name of the print composition, the guide works